# Javascript splitting string in to two parts number and text safely

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I was wondering if there is a safe way (if the data is coming from users) to get the string and the number separated - for example "something-55", "something-124", "something-1291293"
I would want:

something and
55

something and
124

something and
1291293

I mean by a 'safe way' is to be certain I am getting only the number on the end.. if the data is coming from the users "something" could be anything some-thing-55 for example..

I'm looking for a robust way.

Comment: `var parts = str.split('-')`

Comment: what if the string has something-somethingelse-55

Comment: Then you've just changed the entire premise of your question. Be accurate, and you'll get working solutions for your issue.

Comment: if user enters something-123-something-67 what is the expected output?    
i agree with @adeneo

Comment: What if it's `"hello2222Kitty002224344stack99error-22"`, or `"99bottles-of-33-beer-on-the-1st-wall"`, who knows?

Comment: 123 is not on the end its in the middle so the expected would be something-123-something and 67

Comment: If it's on the end, separated with hyphen, `str.split('-').pop()`

Comment: if im not mistaken 22 is on the end of "hello2222Kitty002224344stack99error-22" so I would expect "hello2222Kitty002224344stack99error" and 22

Comment: Here you go -> http://jsfiddle.net/AMbhn/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, working.

```
var string = 'something-456';
var array = string.split('-');

for (var i = 0;i<array.length;i++){
var number = parseFloat(array[i]);
if(!isNaN(number)){
var myNumber = number;
var mySomething = array[i - 1];
console.log('myNumber= ' + myNumber);
console.log('mySomething= ' + mySomething);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
var input='whatever-you-want-to-parse-324';
var sections=input.split(/[\w]+-/);

alert(sections[sections.length-1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substr` along with `lastIndexOf`:

```
var str = "something-somethingelse-55", 
    text = str.substr(0, str.lastIndexOf('-')),
    number = str.substr(str.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);

console.log(text + " and " + number);
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M8sj8/)**

Answer (score 0):

All though it's a tad late, this would be the most restrictive solution:

```
var regex = /^([-\w])+?-(\d+)$/,
    text = "foo-123",
    match = test.match(regex);
```

You will get a match object back with the following values:

```
[ "foo-123", "foo", "123" ]
```

It's a very strict match so that `" foo-123"` and `"foo-123 "` would not match, and it requires the string to end in one or more digits.